# ¿Cual es el método para encontrar el elemento más largo o el más corto de una lista de cadenas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Probé con `max` y `min` pero no funcionó como lo esperaba. Por ejemplo de la siguiente lista:

```
ejemplo = ["casa", "parque", "dog"]
```

El método, si existe debería devolver el elemento más largo:

```
parque
```

Y el menor es:

```
dog
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La forma más sencilla usando [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) y [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) y estableciendo que la clave para obtener estos valores a partir de la función [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) :

```
print(max(ejemplo, key=len))
print(min(ejemplo, key=len))

parque
dog
```

Nota: Ten en cuenta que esto solo va a retornarte un único valor mínimo o máximo, si quisieras obtener todos los que cumplan dicha condición, podrías hacer:

```
ejemplo = ["casa", "parque", "parqua", "dog"]
print([e for e in ejemplo if len(e) == len(max(ejemplo, key=len))])

['parque', 'parqua']
```